# How to use password verify on the login form php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mysqli, passwords

I used a login form where I was open to SQL injection and I am trying to fix it using prepared statements. I have no idea what is the problem with the code. I have never used a login fform with prepared statements before.

This is what I tried at first.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);

$hash = $password;
if (password_verify($password,$hash)) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    exit(header('location: indexclient.php'));
}
```

and this is what I am trying now.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($hash);
$stmt->fetch();

if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $hash)) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      exit(header('location: indexclient.php'));
} else {
    echo "Invalid login";
}
$stmt->close();
```

The error message I get with the last code is "*Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement*".

Comment: You need to select only the columns you bind, no more or no less. So `SELECT password` or whichever the column is called

Comment: Just get rid of this ugly bind_result() method and fetch a familiar assoc array instead. here is an [example](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/password_hash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the password in the `WHERE` clause (so your second approach is correct), as the hash will be different for each time you use it. Furthermore, you should always select the specific number of columns you need, as you need to define each and every one of them with `bind_result()`. It can work with `SELECT *`, but then you rely on `bind_result()` to cover all possible values - which will break if you suddenly add another column to your table.

```php
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ($user && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
    header('location: indexclient.php');
    exit;
} else {
  echo "Invalid login";
}
$stmt->close();
```